# Running an Infinite loop in a user defined function at the same time main function running

Tags: c

So here is my problem. The program doesn't give desired output. After calling timer function my rest of the code doesn't execute. And if I don't use infinite loop the program doesn't show current date and time continuously.

I want a program that shows the system date and time continuously and that doesn't interfere with main function codes while running.
PS: If there is no infinite loop it shows the time when the program ran. And I want to print time in same line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void timer();
void main ()
{

    printf("/n*-----STORE STOCK MANAGER-----*\n");  
    timer();
    int option;
    l1:
    printf("press \n1 for Manager \n2 for Staff\n");
    printf("Manager or staff:");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
        printf("you're a Manager");
        break;
        
        case 2:;
        printf("You're a staff");
        break;
        
        default:
        printf("Invalid Input! Please Choose the correct option\n\a");
        
    }
    sleep (3);
    system("cls");
    goto l1;
}
void timer()
{
  
  char cur_time[128];
  for(;;)
  {
  time_t      t;
  struct tm*  ptm;
  
  t = time(NULL);
  ptm = localtime(&t);
    
  strftime(cur_time, 128, "%d-%b-%Y  %H:%M:%S", ptm);
  printf("\r Current date and time: %s", cur_time);
  }
}
```

wanted output format :
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/871971824433516554/881205921588609024/unknown.png

this was done without using infinite loop.

Comment: @susanth29 I tried but it gives same output .But thanks for your suggestion I'll put timer();  after  l1:

Comment: Its not the way I wanted my output be .
I want to print current date and time below 
```
 printf("/n*-----STORE STOCK MANAGER-----*\n");  
```

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/871971824433516554/881205921588609024/unknown.png

Comment: Why are you using `goto`?

Comment: `goto` is like overkill for any program. Try avoiding that. There are alternatives...

Comment: @DeBARtha okay  I'll try avoiding them

Answer (score 3):

The main thing you need to do to have 2 separate loops running concurrently is to use some sort of multi-tasking.
You can do that either with threads, or with separate processes.  IMO,  the simplest way to do this is with a simple fork.  *If* your terminal accepts these fairly common escape sequences, you might just want something like:

```
#include <err.h>  
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
void timer(void); 
int            
main(void)  
{           
    fputs("\033[H\033[J", stdout); /* Clear screen */
    fputs("\033[2;1H", stdout); /* Move cursor */
    printf("*-----STORE STOCK MANAGER-----*\n");
    printf("press \n1 for Manager \n2 for Staff\n");
    printf("Manager or staff:");     
    fflush(stdout); /* Always flush before a fork */
    switch( fork() ){     
    case 0: timer();      
    case -1: err(EXIT_FAILURE, "fork");  
    }    
    int option; 
    int c;      
    while( (c = scanf("%d", &option)) != EOF ){ 
            if( c == 0 ){ 
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Input!\n");
                    do c = getchar();  
                    while( c != EOF && c != '\n' );    
            } else switch( option ) {  
                    case 1: printf("you're a Manager\n"); break;
                    case 2: printf("You're a staff\n"); break;
                    default:  
                            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Input!\n");
            }      
    }     
}      
         
void    
timer(void)     
{   
    for( ;; ){    
            char cur_time[128];     
            struct tm*  ptm;         
            time_t t = time(NULL);   
            ptm = localtime(&t);    
            strftime(cur_time, 128, "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S", ptm);
            fputs("\0337", stdout); /* Save cursor position */
            printf("\033[1;1HCurrent date and time: %s", cur_time);
            fputs("\0338", stdout); /* Restore cursor position */
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);  
    }  
}
```

The above uses some terminal command sequences that may or may not work on your system, but such details are beyond the scope of this question.  Libraries like `ncurses` can be helpful to abstract away such details.

Note that if you do this, you may notice that you can close the input stream to the parent (eg, ^d on *nix, or ^z (I think) on Windoze) and one process will terminate but the timer will continue updating.  To deal with that, you probably want to send a TERM to the child, or to the process group.  Details left as an exercise.

Comment: It didn't not work on your system. But I'll make some edits. I hope it runs .
The libraries you used are totally new for me  so I'll learn about them .
: )

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can only achieve what you want with multi-threading, this is just a rough sketch of how you will do it with C and is far from complete.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *timer(void* vargp);
void *interact(void* vargp);

int main ()
{
    printf("*-----STORE STOCK MANAGER-----*\n");  
    pthread_t timer_thread, interact_thread;
    pthread_create(&timer_thread, NULL, timer, NULL); // This opens up a thread
    pthread_create(&interact_thread, NULL, interact, NULL); // This opens up another thread
    pthread_join(timer_thread, NULL); // This waits for the timer thread to finish
}

void *interact(void * vargp) {
    int option;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("press \n1 for Manager \n2 for Staff\n");
        printf("Manager or staff:");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
            printf("you're a Manager");
            break;

            case 2:;
            printf("You're a staff");
            break;

            default:
            printf("Invalid Input! Please Choose the correct option\n\a");

        }
    }

}

void *timer(void* vargp)
{
  char cur_time[128];
  for(;;)
  {
      time_t      t;
      struct tm*  ptm;
      
      t = time(NULL);
      ptm = localtime(&t);
        
      // move your cursor
      strftime(cur_time, 128, "%d-%b-%Y  %H:%M:%S", ptm);
      printf("\r Current date and time: %s", cur_time);
  }
}
```

Consider adding sleep in the infinite loop in timer, for it will consume a lot of resources otherwise. Also, you need to set the cursor to it's original position in timer. Take the time to see how you will do that in your system.

Comment: I'm new to programming and I don't know anything about multi-threading but I guess there's no choice but  learning it 
and your code gave me some knowledge and idea about it 
Thank you for helping me

Comment: Glad that it helps. Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).